# Checking a word read in from a file against strings in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, char, duplicates

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work. I'm having to do a frequency check of a list of words from a file, and when reading them in I'm trying to check the current word against the elements in the string array, and making sure they're not equal before I add it. Here's the code:

```
fin.open(finFile, fstream::in);

if(fin.is_open()) {
    int wordArrSize;
    while(!fin.eof()) {
        char buffer[49]; //Max number chars of any given word in the file
        wordArrSize = words.length();

        fin >> buffer;

        if(wordArrSize == 0) words.push_back(buffer);

        for(int i = 0; i < wordArrSize; i++) { //Check the read-in word against the array
            if(strcmp(words.at(i), buffer) != 0) { //If not equal, add to array
                words.push_back(buffer);
                break;
            }
        }



        totNumWords++; //Keeps track of the total number of words in the file
    }
    fin.close();
```

This is for a school project. We're not allowed to use any container classes so I built a structure to handle expanding the char** array, pushing back and popping out elements, etc.

Comment: @Alex, why on earth shouldn't he ask homework questions?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I thought they were banned?

Comment: @Alex, no, we are just not tagging questions with [tag:homework] anymore. A homework question is no different from any other question. You can read about it in the [tag:homework] tag info

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Fair enough. I can't edit my comment anymore, so I shall delete, as one of the answers clears up what I was trying to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < wordArrSize; i++) { //this part is just fine
    if(strcmp(words.at(i), buffer) != 0) { //here lies the problem
         words.push_back(buffer);
         break;
    }
}
```

You will enter your `if` statement each time the current word doesn't match the `i`th word in the array. So, most of the times, it will be the very first iteration when you will enter the loop. This means that in the beginning of the cycle (on the first word inside your string list that doesn't match the buffer) you will add the buffer to the string list and break the cycle.

What you should do is finish checking the whole `words` array, and only then add the buffer into the array. So you should have something like this:

```
bool bufferIsInTheArray = false;//assume that the buffered word is not in the array.
for(int i = 0; i < wordArrSize; i++) { 
    if(strcmp(words.at(i), buffer) == 0) {
         //if we found a MATCH, we set the flag to true
         //and break the cycle (because since we found a match already
         //there is no point to continue checking)
         bufferIsInTheArray = true;
         break;
    }
//if the flag is false here, that means we did not find a match in the array, and 
//should add the buffer to it.
if( bufferIsInTheArray == false )
    words.push_back(buffer);
}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! I don't know why this didn't dawn on me earlier. Seemed like my logic was full-proof at first

Answer (score 1):

i think your code `words.push_back(buffer);` should come outside the for loop. 
Put a flag to check if you found the buffer in array inside for loop and according to flag add it to array outside the for loop

Comment: Tried that and no go. 

This doesn't have anything to do with strcmp() taking two char*'s does it? The buffer[49] should decay to a pointer when being passed unless I'm missing something. There's really no other explanation...This check should be cut and dry argh

Comment: Are you sure. the modification i meant was exactly coded in above answer Did you tried with that answer. In your code if any one word differs from one in words then its added to the array